# Gutenberg DatePicker component with time set to zero

Tags: javascript, block-editor, date, datepicker, react

I'm using the following code to get and set a date meta value for a CPT in Gutenberg (some code omitted for brevity):

```
const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp(
    'postType',
    'activity',
    'meta'
);

const startDate = meta['_my_start_date'];

function onUpdateStartDate(value) {
    setMeta({ ...meta, '_my_start_date': value });
}

...

<PanelRow className="edit-activity-start-date">
    <span>{__('Activity Start Date', 'my-domain')}</span>
    <Dropdown
        placement="middle left"
        renderToggle={(({ isOpen, onToggle }) => (
            <Button isLink={true} onClick={onToggle} aria-expanded={isOpen}>
                {startDate ? dateI18n('j F, Y', startDate) : __('Pick a date', 'my-domain')}
            </Button>
        ))}
        renderContent={() => (
            <DatePicker
                currentDate={startDate}
                onChange={(newDate) => onUpdateStartDate(newDate)}
                startOfWeek={1}
            />
        )}>
    </Dropdown>
</PanelRow>
```

The thing is that the DatePicker component also stores the current time for the selected date (example: 2023-11-09T11:12:06). Is there a way to set the time in the DatePicker component to ZERO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself. You need to modify the `onUpdateStartDate()` function:

```
function onUpdateStartDate(value) {
    const date = new Date(value);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setMeta({ ...meta, '_my_start_date': date });
}
```